# YouTube subscribe button in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, subscribe

How do I add to an iPhone application, a button that will subscribe to a YouTube channel?

I tried using:

```
-(void)subscribe:(id)sender
    {
        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=",YouTubeUserName];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    }
```

but this shows a Youtube screen, where I have a login/sign in button. When pressing login it  leads to a 404 page not found error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: this works: `-(void)subscribe:(id)sender
{   
    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://m.youtube.com/profile?gl=US&warned=True&client=mv-google&hl=en&user=",YouTubeUserName];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Youtube's API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions.html#Adding_a_subscription) to get this done. It's more complicated since you will need to authenticate the user beforehand but is a more thorough and seamless approach for getting this done.

Comment: ok, but how would i use the subscription API? any code sample?

Comment: Google's [GData examples](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) should help get you started.

Comment: It is very similar to consuming any xml webservice SOAP or not. http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

Comment: already seen that, but there are no subscription examples. i'm talking specifically about the iphone api.

Comment: You'll need to imitate the calls that already exist and simply plug in subscription methods. A sample YouTube client exists [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FYouTubeSample). I haven't seen an already-made Objective-C example for subscriptions so you'll have to take it from there.

Comment: @ Matt Bishop: GData examples not running for iPhone can u explain by any source code ?